# Iteration into std::vector<string>

Tags: c++, parameters, while-loop, iterator, stdvector

I have a `vector` of string parameters...

```
|name1|value1|name2|value2|...
```

I wanna iterate and cache the name into a string and add it into a `vector` of names and make the same thing with the `value`. They are in a `std::vector<string>`.

I do it:

```
std::vector<string> names;
std::vector<string> values;
std::vector<string>::iterator pit = p.begin();

while(pit != p.end()){
   string name = *pit;
   pit++;
   string value = *pit;
   pit++;
   names.push_back(name);
   values.push_back(value);
}
```

But it returns an access violation in `vector`. It is accessing a bad location returning a `<BadPtr>`.
How to do this iteration?
Does it have a way of do it using for each?

Comment: You're pushing `name` twice; `value` goes unused; does your compiler not warn you about this?! Also, I hope you first assert that the number of elements in the vector is even....!

Comment: Also, are you sure you want `pit++` and not `++pit`?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your input, but you are iterating twice within the loop without checking if the iterator has run off the end of the vector.

Comment: @Deduplicator that will be optimised by any decent compiler and has no effect on the OP's code

Comment: here you are incrementing `pit` two time in loop without checking that if it is `end`, is causing problem.

Comment: You should check after the first iterator iteration that it's not pointing at the end: `string name = *pit;
   pit++;
   if (pit == p.end())
     break;
   string value = *pit;`

Comment: @EdChum: Yes, in this case, that should be true. But why rely on compiler-optimization when there's no advantage to doing so? Especially as you won't change your code for the instances, relatively rare though they may be, when the compiler cannot optimize the sub-optimal instruction to the same machine-code as the optimal one?

Comment: @Deduplicator I agree with the use semantics in being clear in your code and not to rely on a compiler but the second point still stands that in this case the side effect is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```
std::vector<string> names;
std::vector<string> values;
std::vector<string>::iterator pit = p.begin();

while(pit != p.end()){
   string name = *pit;
   pit++;
   if(pit == p.end())
   break;
   string value = *pit;
   pit++;
   names.push_back(name);
   values.push_back(name);
}
```

As i said in my comment that problem could be, you didn't put any checking after incrementing `pit` second time.

Comment: Er.. surely you want this `if(pit == p.end()) break;`

Comment: If this solves your problem, it means you have a name without a value associated (your vector size is not even), which is probably an issue for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how it can be done using standard algorithm `std::partition_copy`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> p = { "name1", "value1", "name2", "value2" };
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    std::vector<std::string> values;

    names.reserve( ( p.size() + 1 ) / 2 );
    values.reserve( p.size() / 2 );

    unsigned int i = 0;

    std::partition_copy( p.begin(), p.end(),
                         std::back_inserter( names ),
                         std::back_inserter( values ),
                         [&]( const std::string & ) { return i ^= 1; } );

    for ( const auto &s : p ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( const auto &s : names ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( const auto &s : values ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
name1 value1 name2 value2 
name1 name2 
value1 value2
```

The same can be done using the range based for statement

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> p = { "name1", "value1", "name2", "value2" };
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    std::vector<std::string> values;

    names.reserve( ( p.size() + 1 ) / 2 );
    values.reserve( p.size() / 2 );

    unsigned int i = 0;

    for ( const std::string &s : p )
    {
        if ( i ^= 1 ) names.push_back( s );
        else values.push_back( s );
    }

    for ( const auto &s : p ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( const auto &s : names ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( const auto &s : values ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thus your loop can look more simpler like

```
    unsigned int i = 0;

    for ( const std::string &s : p )
    {
        if ( i ^= 1 ) names.push_back( s );
        else values.push_back( s );
    }
```

As you see the body of the loop consists only from two statements instead of six or eight statements if to use your approach.